# execute trigger conditionally user Oracle

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, triggers, oracle12c

I want to condition the execution of the trigger to the oracle user.
If it is the Oracle user : X, then do not execute the trigger otherwise yes.

I created a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_SESSION_USER 
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    user_name_current VARCHAR2(50);
    resultat NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
user_name_current := USER;
IF user_name_current = 'X' THEN
 resultat := 0;
end if;
RETURN resultat;
END;
```

Called the function in a trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TEST"."table1_trigger"
BEFORE UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
-- WHEN (GET_SESSION_USER() = 1)
DECLARE
   ...
BEGIN
IF (GET_SESSION_USER() = 1) THEN
   ...
END IF;
```

`-- WHEN (GET_SESSION_USER() = 1)` return error : ORA-04076: Invalid NEW or OLD specification. So I put a if :
`if (GET_SESSION_USER() = 1) then` this line works, do I have to do a global if ? Can we do better ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need a function? Check user in trigger - not in its `when` clause, though, but `if-then-else`.

Why you can't use `when` clause along with function call? Because [create trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_7004.htm) documentation says:

- This condition must contain correlation names and cannot contain a query
- You cannot invoke PL/SQL functions or methods in the trigger condition

---

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE table1
  2  (
  3     name   VARCHAR2 (20)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table1_trigger
  2     BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  3     ON table1
  4  BEGIN
  5     IF USER = 'SCOTT'
  6     THEN
  7        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Hello, ' || USER);
  8     ELSE
  9        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('You aren''t Scott');
 10     END IF;
 11  END;
 12  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SHOW USER
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> INSERT INTO table1 (name) VALUES ('Littlefoot');
Hello, SCOTT

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

Hardcoding SCOTT in 40 triggers is a tedious job and - possibly - useless (if you decide to move that code into another schema and SCOTT becomes PETER or something else). In that case, you can create function and use it - not in trigger's `when` clause, though - but in `if-then-else`:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_session_user
  2    RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS
  4  BEGIN
  5    RETURN CASE WHEN USER = 'SCOTT' THEN 1
  6                ELSE 0
  7           END;
  8  END;
  9  /

Function created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table1_trigger
  2     BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  3     ON table1
  4  BEGIN
  5     IF get_session_user = 1                       --> here
  6     THEN
  7        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Hello, ' || USER);
  8     ELSE
  9        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('You aren''t Scott');
 10     END IF;
 11  END;
 12  /

Trigger created.

SQL> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('x');
Hello, SCOTT

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do you need a function ?  => So as not to hard code "SCOTT" in the 40 triggers. Triggers have many rows. Maybe we can :  
IF USER = 'SCOTT'
     THEN
        exit or return ?
     ELSE
        ...

Comment: I see; OK, have a look at edited answer, maybe that's what would help in what you're doing.